# Send information from activity via network

Tags: java, android

I want to send the data I get in onLocationChanged() via tcp/ip. I can read the location and network works, too: I can connect and send data.
The problem is: Network can't be in the Activity-thread, but onLocationChanged() has to. Now here is my question:
How do I get the location information from the activity thread to the network thread?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have to send the data over and over again and don't want to reconnect every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems as if I can access the socket created in the network-thread directly from the activity thread. (At least I didn't get any false behavior yet...)

It didn't work at first, but that was because of a rather unrelated bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
onLocationChanged()
{
     new Thread(){
              public void run(){
                       //POST YOUR DATA.
              }
     }.start();
}
```

Comment: I need to send the data over and over again. Do I have to reconnect every time I get new data?

Comment: How? When the thread is newly created every time I get data, I have to reconnect every time, right?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start a separate thread or use an `AsyncTask` to perform network operations, since you're not allowed to tie up the UI thread with a potentially long-running operation.

Comment: Yes I know. But AsyncTask only allows the network thread to talk to the UI, not the UI to the network thread, or am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, but the UI thread can start the `AsyncTask` and pass it the required information.

Comment: So I have to reconnect every time I have new information? (probably every second)

Comment: You may consider using a `Service` -- see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html